# Mathematica doesn't solve linear system of equations that emerges from finite difference method

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, finite-difference-method

I want to solve the ODE $$u''(x)+u(x)=e^{-x^2}$$
$$u(0)=u(10)=0$$ using finite difference method.
I divide the interval $[0,10]$ uniformly by $x_i=0+ih$ using step size $h=\frac{10}{11}$.
By discretizing the equation I got $$\frac{u_{i+1}-2u_i+u_{i-1}}{h^2}+u_i=e^{-x_i^2}$$ so my code is

```
Clear["Global`*"]
u[0] = 0;
u[10] = 0;
a = 0;
b = 10;
n = 10;
h[n_] := (b - a)/(n + 1)
x[i_] := a + i*h[n]
eqs = Table[{(u[x[i + 1]] - 2*u[x[i]] + u[x[i - 1]])/(h[n])^2 + 
      u[x[i]] == E^-(x[i])^2}, {i, 1, 10, h[n]}];


vars = Table[{u[x[i]], u[x[i - 1]], u[x[i + 1]]}, {i, 1, 10, h[n]}]
vars2 = {vars};
varsflat = Flatten[vars2];
eqsflat = Flatten[eqs]
varsfinal = Delete[varsflat, 2]

Solve[eqsflat, varsfinal]
```

essentially, what I did is make a table of all equations (called it eqsflat) and a table of all the variables (varsfinal) so I can put them into Solve in order to solve the system of linear equations, but Mathematica does nothing, maybe It cannot accept variables of the form u[i]?

I can't understand what is wrong with my code, can you explain?

Comment: Set the variables automatic, that is  `Solve[eqsflat]`

Comment: It's a collection of simple mistakes. 1. `{i, 1, 10, h[n]}` should be `{i, 1, 10}` both in `eqs` and `vars`. 2. The way you define `varsfinal` is just confusing, anyway, the following will work: `varsfinal = Table[u[x[i]], {i, 1, 10}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to simplify and generalize  your code:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
n = 25;
u[0] = 0;
u[n] = 0;
a = 0;
b = 10;
h = (b - a )/n;
x[i_] := a + i  h
eqs = Table[ (u[ i + 1 ] - 2*u[ i ] + u[ i - 1 ])/(h )^2 + u[ i ] ==E^-(x[i])^2 , {i, 1, n - 1}] ;
vars = Table[u[i], {i, 1, n - 1}] ;
sol = Solve[eqs , vars] // Flatten;
Table[{x[i], u[i]} /. sol, {i, 0, n}] // ListPlot
```

[image]

Hope it helps!